# Can matplotlib.animation display frames while saving those into a file?

Tags: matplotlib, animation

When I execute `animator.save()`, `plt.show()` does not show the plot until the save process is finished. I have a Python code that uses the animation library to display data received over network, and I would like to record the data that has been displayed. Is there any way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the figure directly in the update function:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
l, = ax.plot(range(10),[0]*10,'r-')
ax.set_ylim(0,1)

def animate(i):
    y = np.random.random(size=(10,))
    l.set_ydata(y)
    fig.savefig(f'test_{i}.png')
    return l,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=10)
```